# Fixing scala compiler and library in IntelliJ 13

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, intellij-13

I have intellij 13 ultimate.

I had scala 2.10.3 installed, and recently upgraded to 2.11 using homebrew.

When I open a sbt project, it may have a different scala version and if it does then it starts to download etc.

Will IntelliJ automatically use the correct compiler for a sbt project once it finishes downloading everything?

I currently have these errors which I'm not sure how to fix:

[image]